# Up and down keys not working in Eclipse template proposals

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Since a couple of days I am no more able to move the cursor in Eclipse *Template Proposals*.

I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>, the template proposals pop up but then when I press the <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> Eclipse moves the cursor in the text and **not** in the template proposals.

Which parameters should I set in the *Preferences* → *General* → *Keys* list  to restore the default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try 'Restore defaults' in Preferences > General > Keys?

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice the button!

Comment: It's awkward that up/down keyboard don't work in proposal popup. I wonder 'Restore defaults' solve the problem.